# Magento. Redirect to specific store view

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

We have multi-website(5) multi-store-view(13) shop.

What we need is that only 3 store view from 1 shop are allowed to checkout. Therefore the problem is how to redirect users from other shops to the same products on specified store view.

For example user watches product on mk_nn_eng and click @Button@, after that he is redirected to mu_aa_ENG **AND sees the same product**, he was observing but on specified store view.

How to perform such redirect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's the same item, it will have the same `id`. And you can link to an item by it's `id` using the format (assuming you have different domains set up for each view):

> www.DomainForStoreViewYouWant.com/catalog/product/view/id/{{product.id}}

Where you would get the `id` with something like `$product->getId();` depending on the product object in the file you're looking at.

So the button you mentioned would just be the above link.

Is this what you had in mind?

**`Update:`**

If it's the same domain for each view, you could add the storecode to the end: `?___store=storecode`

Comment: Well, basically no. I have single domain for all store views. Websites differs only by base url, but store views in single website don't have any difference.

Comment: In which case you can add: ?___store=storecode to the end instead.